# Is it possible to use Paypal with base currency INR?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express

Currently i am developing magento 1.9 website with base currency INR,
Also website has multiple currencies. Like USD, EURO, AUD.

Is it possible to pay with paypal when website's current currency is USD or AUD or EURO,

I already setup paypal, but during its doesn't redirecting to paypal.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Might help you.

[Paypal Multi Currency Extension](https://www.magecoders.com/paypal-multicurrency-pro)

Answer (score 2):

First of all yes, it will be possible to accept Paypal payment through INR currency. Reference as below:

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services-Archive/Receive-money-in-INR-curreccy/m-p/201016#M3429

Now, in magento to allow base currency to be INR, Override **app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php**

Change:

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN','NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
```

And add INR as below:

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN','NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB','INR');
```